# Project creation failed (InstallShield in vs2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield-le

I can not create a setup project in visual studio 2012 profissional (enable installshield limited edition)
I get the following error:

".. project creation failed" and no more detail

already checked the folder permissions and have reseted the settings of visual studio, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is included in VS, but does not work, then the reinstalled.. 
I solved the problem with it here:

> InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 
> InstallShield®
>   Limited Edition for Visual Studio* enables you to:
>
> Build flexible installation projects for applications built with
>   Visual Studio Jumpstart projects with a simple design environment and
>   Project Assistant Take advantage of Installation Prerequisites and
>   Custom Actions Digitally sign your installers
>
> InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio replaces the
>   functionality provided by the Visual Studio Installer.  Import your
>   existing Visual Studio deployment projects into InstallShield Limited
>   Edition to get started.
>
> How to get InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio
>
> Step 1: Verify that your computer has a network connection. 
> Step
>   2: Go to the download web site. 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239620&lang=1033&ver=pro
>   
> Step 3: Register to download the solution, and install it or save
>   it for deployment to your Team Foundation Server. 
> Step 4: After
>   installation you will need to restart Visual Studio to access
>   InstallShield Limited Edition project type under the Setup and
>   Deployment category.
>
> - InstallShield Limited Edition is included with Visual Studio 2010 and higher versions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solutions, but the below mentioned steps helped me at last. Please try out that if none of the above solutions worked for you.

- Go to Libraries\Documents folder
- Right click on the folder IISExpress and click Properties
- Go to Advanced options
- Under Compress or Encrypt attributes, please uncheck the checkbox
  'Encrypt contents to secure data'
- Click Ok and apply.

Now try to create a project, hope you won't get the error again.